# Is it posible to have jQuery UI autocomplete on a contenteditable div and datepicker working in harmony?

Tags: jquery, contenteditable, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-ui-datepicker

In the forum post ["How to make jquery autocomplete to work for a contenteditable DIV instead of just INPUT, TEXTAREA fields."](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-jquery-autocomplete-to-work-for-a-contenteditable-div-instead-of-just-input-textarea-fields) we see how to get autocomplete working on a contenteditable div element, however combined with datepicker the datepicker simply does not populate the input field.

As you can see in this jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xvnaA/

Anyone have any wise ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of just overriding `$.fn.val` you could redefine it like this:

```
(function ($) {
   var original = $.fn.val;
   $.fn.val = function() {
      if ($(this).is('[contenteditable]')) {
         return $.fn.text.apply(this, arguments);
      };
      return original.apply(this, arguments);
   };
})(jQuery);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xvnaA/27/

Comment: This is some awesomeness right here. It appears to work. I will do some more testing...

Comment: I've discovered a side affect. Upon clicking on the datepicker input field it is emptied as opposed to this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gheqD/ Any ideas?

Comment: I had a look at this in a bit more detail, unfortunately it's not going to work because it means $(this).val() will return an object rather than a string...

Comment: Good stuff! I edited the answer to work on elements with any value of `contenteditable` (e.g. plaintext-only) and to use `.text` instead of `.html` (mimic behavior of `.val` better, reduce possibility of XSS). Some people may want to switch back to `.html`, if they know what they're doing.