# autocomplete with contenteditable div instead of textarea doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm using the autocomplete plugin by Andrew Whitaker, also referenced in this question: 
[jquery autocomplete @mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060536/jquery-autocomplete-mention)

This doesn't work if I use a contenteditable div instead of a textarea.  Here's my code:

```
<div id="MyText" contenteditable="true"></div>​

$("#MyText").bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term,
                results = [];
            if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                term = extractLast(request.term);
                if (term.length > 0) {
                    results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, term);
                } else {
                    results = [startTyping];
                }
            }
            response(results);
        },
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value !== startTyping) {
                var terms = this.value.split(' ');
                terms.pop();
                terms.push("@" + ui.item.value + "</span>");
                this.value = terms.join(" ");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        if (item.label != startTyping) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><div><img src='" + item.icon + "'/></div><div>" + item.label + "</div></div></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        } else {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    };
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836562/is-it-posible-to-have-jquery-ui-autocomplete-on-a-contenteditable-div-and-datepi) ?

Comment: Thanks, I checked it. It solves half my problem.  The issue is that when I select the item from the list, it doesn't get added to the div.

Comment: As of 2019, the answer seem outdated, with the browser console logging a `TypeError`.  [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) has a better, modern example

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main difference between an input/textarea and a contenteditable div is that you access the latter content with the .html() method (instead of the .value or .val() method.

Here is the autocomplete code:

```
$("#MyText")
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term,
                results = [];
            if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                term = extractLast(request.term);
                if (term.length > 0) {
                    results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, term);
                } else {
                    results = [startTyping];
                }
            }
            response(results);
        },
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value !== startTyping) {
                var value = $(this).html();
                var terms = split(value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                $(this).html(terms.join("@"));
                placeCaretAtEnd(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        if (item.label != startTyping) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><div>" + item.label + "</div></div></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        } else {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    }
;
```

**EDIT(2)**: Here is the [**link to the jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/T45rQ/7/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, the problem I'm having (and also with  your jsfiddle) is that the cursor goes to the starting position after selecting the item.  Any idea how to have the cursor appear at the end of the selected item?

Comment: @Prabhu, ok, with the help of Tim Down's answer in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser/4238971#4238971
I've been able to move the cursor to the end. See updated jsfiddle in my answer.

Comment: Very cool.  There's one more issue with the jsFiddle though, hoping you can help me with it.  When you select multiple items, the previously selected item loses the first character (the @ sign).  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: very helpful example!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Above example was not working See this http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/jYJjJ/29/

```
select: function (event, ui) {

            var value = $(this).html();
            var terms = split(value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            $(this).html(terms+", ");
            placeCaretAtEnd(this);

        return false;
    }
```