# Auto suggestion Dictionary for div contenteditable..(don't show popup box just suggestion beside word)

Tags: html

Is there any plugin available for autosuggestion for div `contenteditable=true` tag??
By typing a single letter it shows whole word as a suggestion..
I tried many plugins like auto.js n complete.ly but not working for div..

Comment: possible duplicate of [autocomplete with contenteditable div instead of textarea doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324822/autocomplete-with-contenteditable-div-instead-of-textarea-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: @Moriarty these plugins display popup box for suggestion..I want suggestion beside typed letter..Just like auto.js do in textarea